# Compiler Error variable "Not captured" inside lambda function for threadpool

Tags: c++, multithreading, lambda, scope

I'm learning about multithreading in c++ and am trying to set up a thread pool, but am getting a complier error saying "error: ‘mapperNodes’ is not captured" and "error: ‘command’ is not captured". I've read a bit about using "this" to capture the variables in the lambda, but so far nothing has been working.

How can I use the command and mapperNoders variables in the thread pool lambda function in the code below?

```
void MapReduceServer::spawnMappers() throw() {
  vector<string> mapperNodes(nodes);
  random_shuffle(mapperNodes.begin(), mapperNodes.end());
  string command = buildCommand(mapperNodes[0], executablePath, mapperExecutable, mapOutputPath);

  ThreadPool pool(numMappers);//numMappers = 8

  for (size_t id = 0; id < numMappers; id++) {
    pool.schedule([id] {
      cout << oslock << "Thread (ID: " << id << ") has started." << endl << osunlock;

      spawnWorker(mapperNodes[0], command); /*compiler error here*/

      cout << oslock << "Thread (ID: " << id << ") has finished." << endl << osunlock;
  });
}
```

Comment: @M.M, I think you're mistaken on that.  §11.4.4 of TC++PL 4th ed. explicitly says that an empty argument list may be omitted.  So does, for example, [this article in cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: @Paulo1205 cool, good to know

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you wrote `pool.schedule([id]{ /*...*/ });`, you told the compiler that your lambda only wants *a copy of* the value of the `id` variable, and nothing else.

To make (a copy of) all variables of `MapReduceServer::spawnMappers()` available to the lambda, you can change `[id]` for `[=]`.

Comment: That being said, you probably don't want a *copy* of all available variables.

Comment: @JoelCornett, Agreed, the variable `pool`could be left out.  Perhaps he should use `[id, command, mapperNodes]` instead.

Comment: `[&]` or `[=]` are simplest and usually the best; naming specific members doesn't really gain anything and may in fact hurt performance

Comment: @M.M, I just think that `[&]` (or `[&somevar]`) will not be good is this case, because, as far as I got it, he is creating new threads, as giving references to temporary objects to threads that may outlive their creator is possibly not a good idea.

Comment: @M.M: How so? Are there underlying optimizations at work that take advantage of complete captures?

Comment: Yeah, I saw a guru talk about it the other day but don't remember the details. something to do with it being less work for the compiler if you just let it decide what's necessary