# How to pass in argument to C++ system call

Tags: c++, linux, bash, unix

I have this function to call a bash script in a new thread. However I get the following error:

```
error: ‘systemArgument’ is not capturedsystem(systemArgument.c_str());
```

My function is:

```
void StartScript(int deviceId)
{
   std::thread *StartThread_;
   std::string systemArgument = "./Start.sh " + std::to_string(deviceId);

   StartThread_ = new std::thread([this] ()
   {
      system(systemArgument.c_str());
   });
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compiler Error variable "Not captured" inside lambda function for threadpool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34101482/compiler-error-variable-not-captured-inside-lambda-function-for-threadpool)

Comment: That use of `std::thread` looks _fishy_. Why are you using pointers there?

Comment: Looks like what you want here is:  StartThread_ = new std::thread([this,systemArgument] () {...});